# Supplement / override System.Diagnostic.Trace messages with context from parent TPL Task

Tags: .net, plugins, task-parallel-library

I have a plugin-based system that uses .Net Task<> / TPL heavily to do parallel workflows. The workers are plugins that do various types of tasks and are built outside of the main processing application, compiled as DLLs and dropped into a plugin directory.

The worker plugins will use Trace messages to output what they are doing. I would love to supplement these Trace messages with additional contextual information only known in the parent application. This would also mean that I'd need to somehow figure out what context the trace message was coming from (which Task<> it was coming from)

#### Concrete use-case:

- Parent application picks up "work" to be done from a queue.
- Application finds the appropriate worker-plugin to perform the work type being requested
- Parent creates a new Task<> for the plugin to work within, establishes a WorkID to associated to this work task and starts the process
- When the plugin uses something like Trace.WriteLine(), I would like for that message to be supplemented with the WorkID established from the main application (which the plugin knows nothing about)

I know I could pass in a logging implementation to the plugin, but then I have to re-write all my plugins to expect, and use that logging implementation.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: you should look into "CallContext", regarding tpl - Stephen Cleary has a good writeup here: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/04/implicit-async-context-asynclocal.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per @barakcaf 's suggestion, I looked into `CallContext` which solved my issue.

Example:

```
    public async Task TopFunction(string someContextualData)
    {
        CallContext.LogicalSetData("MyVar", someContextualData);

        await ChildFunction();
    }

    public async Task ChildFunction()
    {
        string someContextualData = (string)CallContext.LogicalGetData("MyVar");
    }
```